# R cannot be resolved to a variable, no other errors, R is generated

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

Yes, I know there are already tons of questions & answers for this one, but I nearly tried everything except delete and throw my computer out:/
I try to summerize what I have tried already:

- Clean and restart
- Update everything
- Project target good
- Project orders
- Check private libraries
- Check Android 4.2 too in Path orders
- All xml are without error
- Actually no other error OR warning than the R files
- Try in Eclipse Juno and brand-new install from google (https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk)
- Removing import android.R from the files
- Delete the R itself from gen folder, it's regenerating within a minute

Anybody with any other idea? I am googling it for a day, no new things come up lately:/

Comment: Post your code with all imports.

Comment: +1 for `but I nearly tried everything except delete and throw my computer out`

Answer (score 0):

If your xml coding is exactly fine means then Check your  `Android Manifest file`.There mainly check the `package name` is exactly same as you mentioned while creating the project.

Answer (score 0):

Check if any imports contains capital letters in your drawable folders usualy resource file does not get created when a error occured in project so better if you check

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your folders which in your project, are have :

1. *no capital leter starts
2. *no start with numeric value of your files.
3. *no starts with _ ,*,(just start with alfanumeric char ) char of your files

Comment: @Judit did you try these?

Comment: or if you put your project to github I can investigate and help you

Answer (score 0):

1. go to Build path -> configure build path -> Library check if any dependency folder contains red * for missing dependency.
2. Check that your supported library attached multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Check all you .xml files. Just a slightly error can make big problems. The editor might not show where the error is, so look thoroughly!